# Print something on the main text to the begining

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, cross-referencing, auxiliary-files

I want to make something on the main text show on the first line of the first page, i.e. before the main text. Here is an example with some integer as the main text. In particular, I want to show `z = x + y = (12)` there by some magic stuffs, for example, the help of `.aux` file.

I don't know whether it is the same thing as the `toc` content since both of them are supposed to run twice.

However, I may not describe the problem clearly with this title. But what I want to say is all in the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
z = x+y = ( ). % 12 is supposed to be there without move this line to the end

\newcounter{x}
\newcounter{y}
\newcounter{z}

\setcounter{x}{5}
\setcounter{y}{7}

x = \thex, y= \they.
\end{document}
```

I have no particular solution to this so I couldn't give any serious attempt.

Comment: The question title would be much friendlier to me at least XD if it was something like: evaluting an expression before setting the values of its variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `totcount` and some arithmetic facilities. Two runs of LaTeX are necessary if one counter changes value.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newtotcounter{x}
\newtotcounter{y}

\begin{document}

$x+y=\the\numexpr\totvalue{x}+\totvalue{y}\relax$

\setcounter{x}{5}
\setcounter{y}{7}

$x = \thex$, $y= \they$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Friendlier syntax with `xfp`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount,xfp}

\newtotcounter{x}
\newtotcounter{y}

\begin{document}

$x+y=\inteval{\totvalue{x}+\totvalue{y}}$

\setcounter{x}{5}
\setcounter{y}{7}

$x = \thex$, $y= \they$.

\end{document}
```