# How could I put a different gradetable in the exam package on the begining of the document?

Tags: exam

I want to DIY the gradetable in the [`exam`](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/exam.cls) package but it is hard for me to deal with the source code. Here is my solution but I have to put it on the end of the document. In order to put it in the beginning, I use the `totcount` package in this demonstration with the help of egreg from my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510967/print-something-on-the-main-text-to-the-begining).

This file should be run twice.

```
\documentclass[answers,12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{xparse,expl3}
\usepackage{totcount,xinttools,xfp}
\usepackage{tabu}
%\newtotcounter{sumpoints}
\newtotcounter{examSection}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_brooksexam_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\makepart}{ m m m }{
    \clist_gput_right:Nn \g_brooksexam_clist {#3}
    \stepcounter{examSection}
    %\immediate\write\@mainaux{%
         %\string\gdef\string\pointsofsection@\roman{examSection}{#3}%
    }%

    %\addtocounter{sumpoints}{#3}
    \begin{EnvFullwidth}
        \textbf{\Roman{examSection} \quad #1(each~#2~points,total~#3~points)}
    \end{EnvFullwidth}
}

%% \NewDocumentCommand{\commlistOnEnd}{}{
%%    \begin{center}
%%        \begin{tabular}{*{\totvalue{examSection}}{c|}}
%%          \xintFor ##1 in \g_brooksexam_clist \do {\xintifForFirst{}{&}##1}
%%        \end{tabular}
%%    \end{center}    
%%}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%I use the table by the package to see what is in the .aux file
\begin{center}
\gradetable[h][questions]
\end{center}


%\commlistOnEnd  %% not try this way

\begin{questions}
\makepart{Single Choices}{10}{20}
\question[10]
I love \hfill (\quad).

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice he
\choice she
\CorrectChoice you
\choice my dog
\end{oneparchoices}

\question[10]
I love \hfill (\quad).

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice he
\choice she
\CorrectChoice you
\choice my dog
\end{oneparchoices}

\makepart{Blank}{10}{30}
\question[10]
I love \fillin[You][1in].
\question[10]
I love \fillin[You][1in].
\question[10]
I love \fillin[You][1in].

\makepart{Computations}{20}{40}
\question[20]
Why you love me?
\begin{solution}
You are temperament and beautiful.
\end{solution}

\question[20]
Why you love me?
\begin{solution}
You are temperament and beautiful.
\end{solution}
\end{questions}

%\commlistOnEnd   %% neigher this way
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**  Here are a part of the code in the .aux file:

```
relax 
\gdef\pointsofq@i{10}
\gdef\bonuspointsofq@i{0}
\gdef\pointsofq@ii{10}
\gdef\bonuspointsofq@ii{0}
\gdef\pointsofq@iii{10}
\gdef\bonuspointsofq@iii{0}
\gdef\pointsofq@iv{10}
\gdef\bonuspointsofq@iv{0}
\gdef\pointsofq@v{10}
\gdef\bonuspointsofq@v{0}
\gdef\pointsofq@vi{20}
\gdef\bonuspointsofq@vi{0}
\gdef\pointsofq@vii{20}
\gdef\bonuspointsofq@vii{0}
\PgInfo{question@1}{1}
\PgInfo{question1@object1}{1}
\newlabel{question@1}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{firstpoints@onpage@1}{{1}{1}}
\PgInfo{question1@object2}{1}
\PgInfo{question1@object3}{1}
\PgInfo{question1@object4}{1}
\PgInfo{question1@object5}{1}
\PgInfo{question@2}{1}
```

The `exam` package author Philip S. Hirschhorn said that

```
% \gdef commands for exam@lastpage, exam@numpoints,
% exam@numbonuspoints, exam@numquestions, exam@numparts,
% exam@numsubparts and exam@numsubsubparts are written to the .aux
% file via \AtEndDocument.
```

And

```
 % We make sure the user said \addpoints, and then make sure
  % that this isn't the first run of LaTeX (by checking that
  % \exam@numpoints is defined).
```

Then

```
% When we get to \find@qrange, we know we're doing a table indexed by
% question numbers and that this is not the first run of latex.
```

Last to construct the table.

So, I think I can try with `\@ifundefined{exam@numpoints}%`, `\immediate\write\@mainaux
      {\string\gdef\string\exam@lastpage{\arabic{page}}}%` and `% See if this has changed from the last run of LaTeX:
    \CheckIfChanged@hlf{numpoints}{exam@numpoints}%` arroding to the author. Specifically, I can use `etoolbox` package to attach my code to AtEndDocument.

Comment: I find a similar questions of my in there:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495534/custom-points-table-for-exam/495723#495723 I think I will learn from this. I'm sorry to ask this question.

Comment: I solved my problems via the hlep of @Andrew 's edited answer of the questions linked above. Thanks a lot to him.